# scapy: How to get ByteEnumField value from fields_desc?

Tags: python, scapy

I'm using the bgp layer of scapy and I'm wondering if it is possible to get some constant values defined in scapy Fields class.

For example the class `BGPPathAttr` contains a field `type_code` that refers to a map containing an association between `NEXT_HOP` and the magic number 3 defined in the RFC 4271. I would like to access to the value 3 by making a statement that looks like `BGPPathAttr.type_code.NEXT_HOP`

Thanks

A an extract of the scapy code `./scapy/scapy/contrib/bgp.py`

```
path_attributes = {
    0: "Reserved",
    1: "ORIGIN",  # RFC 4271
    2: "AS_PATH",  # RFC 4271
    3: "NEXT_HOP",  # RFC 4271
    [...]
}

class BGPPathAttr(Packet):

   name = "BGPPathAttr"
   fields_desc = [
       ByteEnumField("type_code", 0, path_attributes)
   ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi,

You can use the `s2i` attribute (and `i2s` for the reverse translation):

```
>>> BGPPathAttr.type_code.s2i['NEXT_HOP']
3
>>> BGPPathAttr.type_code.i2s[3]
'NEXT_HOP'
```